# Finding AWS Account ID with S3 Bucket Name

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I will get a JSON from my client in which it has only bucket name and now i have to find out AWS Account ID using that and add that account to SNS Permission policy

I tried using below code and i was able to find Name and Canonical ID. Is there any way i can find Account ID using name or canonical ID.

Could someone help

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsserviceaccessKey, awsservicesecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    System.out.println(s3Client.getS3AccountOwner());
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** This is now possible, via a small security hack. See: [How to find the AWS Account ID of any S3 Bucket](https://tracebit.com/blog/2024/02/finding-aws-account-id-of-any-s3-bucket/)

--- Old answer:

It is not possible to obtain an AWS Account ID from a bucket name.

You will need to request the bucket owner to provide their Account ID.

Comment: Is there any way to get complete ARN for a S3 Bucket? ("Arn": "arn:aws:s3::THISISYOURNUMERICACCOUNTNUMBER:user/nurav")

Comment: @nurav This questions appears unrelated to your original question about obtaining an Account ID from a bucket name. Please create a new Question and provide appropriate details.

Comment: There are now some techniques available online to do this